# PHP: Regex alternative to array_intersect

Tags: php, regex, array-intersect

I'm using a method that takes an array of words and removes any that don't match the following:

```
return is_array( $var ) ? array_intersect( $var,
    array(
        'current_page_item',
        'current-menu-item',
        'current_page_parent',
        'current_page_ancestor',
        'current-menu-ancestor',
        'first',
        'last',
        'vertical',
        'horizontal'
    )
) : '';
```

How can I modify this so that I can include `li(?:-[a-z_-]+)?`? (Examples: `li`, `li-align_left`, `li-magnify`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use **[array_filter](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php)** to achieve this:

```
return is_array( $var ) ? array_filter($var, function($ele) {
  return preg_match('/li(?:-[a-z_-]+)?/', $ele);
}) : '';
```